# Is there a potential energy formula for a catenary curve?

Tags: physics, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to find the minimum energy point of a catenary curve. Can anyone please let me know whether there is a potential energy or energy formula for a catenary curve ?

Especially I would like to know when the end points of a catenary changes it's position, I would like to know how the energy of a particular point on a catenary changes and where that particular point will reach in position.

Comment: What do you mean by energy formula for the catenary? Do you mean the total energy of the configuration in a gravitational field? The potential energy cannot be defined at a particular point of the catenary. You can define an energy density at that point, however (energy/unit length).

Comment: Why, of course there is a formula, and it is the same as for any other curve or no curve at all: $E=mgh$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The catenary, help with the equation for a hanging chain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261921/the-catenary-help-with-the-equation-for-a-hanging-chain)